# How to modify Totals row in Access 2013

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm trying to modify a total query so that if the amount of the sum surpasses 1000 for example it changes the value in 2 fields. for example, 1000 grams change to 1 kilogram, and vice versa.
For example, if I have 20 items in grams, and the total of the sum of those 20 items is 1200 grams, how do I make it so that it automatically changes it to 1.2 kilograms. How do I make it detect that its over 1000 to convert it from grams to kilograms.

Comment: Update your question with some details: the query, the fields and expected output. It's very unclear as it stands.

Comment: @Mackan just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Function presentFormattedWeight(Weight as Long) as String
Dim KgWeight as Long
Dim GramWeight as Long
KgWeight =0
if(Weight mod 1000)>0 then
    KgWeight = Weight\1000
    GramWeight = Weight mod 1000
else
    GramWeight = Weight
end if
if KgWeight >0 then
     presentFormattedWeight = KgWeight & "." & GramWeight & "Kg"
else
    presentFormattedWeight =  GramWeight & "grams"
end if
End Function
```

Comment: how would I use that in access to try it?

Comment: It is not very clear where you want to use it but the function could be public in a module..  So it would be available globally and use it like this    if it is in a query:WeightRepresentation:presentFormattedWeight(weight)